# Button Inside Android ListView doesnt respond to clicks

Tags: android, android-listview, android-button

I have a default ListView that i have added my custom views for the list items, but the buttons inside of these views are not clickable most of the time. I output a Log.v when the button receives a click event, but i have to tap the button almost a dozen times before it will register the click.

The other problem related tot his that i am having is that when the button is pressed i want an animation to happen revealing a menu sliding out from beneath it. At the moment i have tried several different methods like making a custom class for the views versus just using a layout inflater to get the relativeLayout object for the view, but nothing is working properly. I have even tried using `listview.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();` but that only has a pop-into-place for the extended view when i want an animation.

I have searched everywhere and it seems like the only possible solutions are to either rewrite my own custom listview or to use a linearlayout with a scrollview. The latter seems easier but i dont think it is nearly as optimized as the listview is.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, if you need to see some code, please let me know...

Thanks!

UPDATE:

the `getView()` contains this:

```
    Holder hold;
    convertView = friends.get(position);
    hold = new Holder();
    hold.pos = position;
    convertView.setTag(hold);
    return convertView;
```

basically i pass an `ArrayList<RelativeLayout>`, at the moment, to the Adapter so that i dont have to create a new view each time and so that the animation will stay animated when i scroll down...

inside the `OnCreate()` for this activity i set that `ArrayList<RelativeLayout>` with this next code, but this is only temporary as i plan to use another method later, like an Async task or something so that this view contains some data...

```
    RelativeLayout temp;
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++){
        temp = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        final LinearLayout extraListItemInfo = (LinearLayout) temp.findViewById(R.id.extraListItemInfo);

        Button infoBtn = (Button) temp.findViewById(R.id.infoBtn);
        infoBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("ListItem", "Button has been clicked... ");
                extraListItemInfo .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                ExpandAnimation closeAnim = new ExpandAnimation(extraListItemInfo , animHeight);
                closeAnim.setDuration(750);
                closeAnim.setFillAfter(true);

                if(extraListItemInfo .getTag() == null || !extraListItemInfo .getTag().equals("expanded")){
                    extraListItemInfo .getLayoutParams().height = 0;
                    friendInfoList.startAnimation(closeAnim.expand());
                    extraListItemInfo .setTag("expanded");
                }else if(extraListItemInfo .getTag().equals("expanded")){
                    extraListItemInfo .startAnimation(closeAnim.collapse());
                    extraListItemInfo .setTag("closed");
                }
                //((BaseAdapter) listview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); i tried it here once but then left it
    //as the only action inside the listview's onitemclick()
            }
        });

        listItems.add(temp);
    }
```

this is the list item that i am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/darkgrey"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/extraListItemInfo "
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listItemInfo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout04"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_list_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView04"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_d" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView04"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView04"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="17dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout03"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_list_height" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_d" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView03"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="17dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_list_height" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_d" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView02"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="17dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_list_height" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_d" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="17dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_list_height">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_d" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="17dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/listItemInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:background="@drawable/friend_cell_background2x"
        android:clickable="true" >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/leftLayout"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgCompany"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/user2x" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/online_indicator2s" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftLayout"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblCompanyName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Contact Name"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" >

            </TextView>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblReawrdDesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Last Played Offer"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="17dp" >

            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook_btn2x" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/infoBtn"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView4"
            android:background="@drawable/info_btn2x"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/infoBtn"
            android:text="Follows 30+"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="11dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:background="@drawable/fan_btn2x"
            android:text="Fans 30+"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="11dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView4"
            android:src="@drawable/google_btn2x" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

sorry for any layout problems that may make things difficult to read... but i hope this helps you guys to understand my problem... Thanks

UPDATE 2:

All of these answers have been helpful in some way, but i think the main issue that i must first fix is why the buttons do not receive click events until i have first scrolled away from that listItem, then back to it, then clicked the button again... If someone can help find a solution to THAT i **think** that everything else will be much easier to solve...
Thanks...

A screenshot as requested, but remember that this shot was taken on a samsung galaxy tab 10.1 and due to me using the same layout for this larger screen, it looks much different from what it does on the phone i usually test with (Motorola droid x that isnt rooted and cant take screenshots...)

[image]

Another Update:
I managed to get the clicking and animation working nicely by Extending ArrayAdapter instead of base adapter. Sadly i am still experiencing problems as only the bottom half of the list is clickable. The top half of the list still behaves as before with the very glitchy click events... Any ideas as to what is happening this time? Thanks...

Comment: Please include the relevant code, to give us context as to why the click listener is not listening.

Comment: What's the code for your adapter's `getView()`? Also, if you are inflating rows, post the xml.

Comment: use android:focasable=false in your xml file i may be work...

Comment: that focusable change isnt working... it seems like im unable to fix an error i found from other people earlier which was where the button's clicks arent registered until the view changes, like through a scrolling event... Im seeing that in the logs because i touch the button several times with nothing happening, then i scroll the list and then for some reason get the events from all of those button clicks...

Comment: Thanks for the screen shot. I still don't see anything obvious, so I'll ask a basic question. Have you tried making the `infoBtn` bigger to ensure that you are hitting the button?

Comment: @Sam Yes, i did think of that and it left me with the same result... ive even tried removing everything else near it (the images and text) and just leaving the button there and that didnt fix it either...

Comment: Is that then list item that you have? (the complex layout that you posted?) I had the same problem and I got it working, it was very, very annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this isn't really an answer, but after rewriting this a few times I managed to fix it so that it functions exactly the way I wanted.

This time I left all of the data separate from each view and had each list item be a custom class inheriting `RelativeLayout` and also implementing its own `OnClickListener` for its specific `infoBtn`.

My adapter now simply extends ArrayAdapter<> and overrides this `getView()` method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView != null && (convertView instanceof FriendListItem2))
        ((FriendListItem2) convertView).setFriendInfo(friends.get(position));
    else
        convertView = new FriendListItem2(getContext(), friends.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

Finally, in the main activity for this page I simply set the `ListView` with an adapter that I passed the data to.

This is all much cleaner than I had before and I wish it hadn't taken several rewrites of the code to get it right. Hopefully someone can benefit from this, though I still have no clue why I was getting a problem before.

Thanks for all previous suggestions.

Comment: Congratulations (if it works it's an answer)! Upvote for coming back and closing the question.

Answer (score 3):

try using this property in the top level layout in which your child views are placed.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Its a bit tricky but I would suggest that if the above line does not work, try toggling between the removing of focusable=true and focusable="false" from the buttons. It should work.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

That is a complex layout to create for every row...

Anyway, when you use the `new` keyword you are creating a different scope. In short your onClickListener does *not* see the 30 different `extraListItemInfo` references you expect it to see.

Try something like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    LinearLayout extraListItemInfo = v.getParent();
    ...
```

Comment: i think this will help me, but the problem isnt what i do with the events, it's getting the events in the first place... See Update 2 for clarification. Also, i tried this and the results were the same as before, except that i agree that this is the better way of doing this.

Comment: Could you post a screen shot? You are **right**, I missed the root cause of your problem. I understand your question (now) but am a little confused by the layout.

Comment: Any other ideas? should i just scrap what i have and try to start over?

Comment: Sorry, no new ideas. I just don't see the reason why the OnClickListener doesn't fire on every click... I would suggest trying to combine the RelativeLayout siblings, but that is only for efficiency.

Comment: Well I fixed it if you wish to see my new solution.

Answer (score 0):

add `android:onClick="onClick"` to your button xml, it'll make it call the `onClick()` method

Comment: The click events are going to the right place, its just they arent being called until i scroll away from that listItem, scroll back to it, then press the button again...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try taking the "android:clicable="true" " from the Relative Layout. When you do that the activity expects you to do make setOnClickListener to that RelativeLayout . It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

you can fire click event on button from getView() method of ListViewAdapter Class.
See this question

[Android : How to set onClick event for Button in List item of ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596199/android-how-to-set-onclick-event-for-button-in-list-item-of-listview).