# Android : How to set onClick event for Button in List item of ListView

Tags: android, listview

I want to add `onClick` event for buttons used in item of `Listview`.
How can I give `onClick` event for buttons in List Item.

Comment: Care to explain with some code you have done???

Comment: Post your code of custom lisview.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098558/listview-with-clickable-editable-widget/27898369#27898369

Comment: I have wrote my solution in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098558/listview-with-clickable-editable-widget/38504831#38504831

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can set the `onClick` event in your custom adapter's `getView` method..
check the link http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.it/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html

Comment: UI operations or listeners should not be done in the Adapter. If i want to get it to the calling activity. How do i do it?

Answer (score 100):

### In Adapter Class

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vehicals_details_row, parent, false);
    Button deleteImageView = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.DeleteImageView);
    deleteImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //...
        }
    });
}
```

But you can get an issue - *listView row not clickable*. Solution:

- make ListView focusable `android:focusable="true"`
- Button not focusable
   `android:focusable="false"`

Comment: Why make `ListView` focusable and `Button` not focusable? I mean what happens when we do this?

Comment: ListView only response on clicking row  but Button will stop getting focus.When we add checkbox, imageview or button then some time Listview stop response on click

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for this solution.  And how  to send the data back to the activity who contain the Listview?

On more clear, how the adapter can send the click event on  a row imageButtowm to the parent activity.  (because I need the parent activity to react.

Comment: @Franck try using handler to send data back.

Comment: This worked perfectly, and must be the right answer. ListView focusable true, button focusable false. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Try This,

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) 
{
   if(convertView == null)
   {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        convertView  = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT, null);
   }

   Button Button1= (Button)  convertView  .findViewById(R.id.BUTTON1_ID);

   Button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
   { 
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) 
       {
           // Your code that you want to execute on this button click
       }

   });


   return convertView ;
}
```

It may help you....

Comment: You must set only one ClickListener per convertView

Comment: But you will create OnClickListener object on every getView, that's not bad?

Answer (score 4):

In your custom adapter inside getView method :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do things Here 
    }
});
```

Comment: Here how to get the list item details like postion and all

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed in many posts but still I could not figure out a solution with:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Below solution will work with any of the ui components : Button, ImageButtons, ImageView, Textview. LinearLayout, RelativeLayout clicks inside a listview cell and also will respond to onItemClick:

Adapter class - getview():

```
    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_ref_row, parent, false);
            }
            final Organization currentOrg = organizationlist.get(position).getOrganization();

            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_check);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    context.doSelection(currentOrg);

                }
            });

       if(currentOrg.isSelected()){
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sub_search_tick);
        }else{
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sub_search_tick_box);
        }

    }
```

In this was you can get the button clicked object to the activity. (Specially when you want the button to act as a check box with selected and non-selected states):

```
    public void doSelection(Organization currentOrg) {
        Log.e("Btn clicked ", currentOrg.getOrgName());
        if (currentOrg.isSelected() == false) {
            currentOrg.setSelected(true);
        } else {
            currentOrg.setSelected(false);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Comment: Here's a download link to a zipped Android Studio Project that does exactly what you want. It works perfectly and is thoroughly tested. http://developersfound.com/ListButtonClickExample.zip
Also the technique in this project also works with the new RecycleLists

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have defined custom adapter for your ListView.

If this is the case then you can assign `onClickListener` for your button inside the custom adapter's `getView()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Class for ArrayList & ArrayAdapter

```
class RequestClass {
    private String Id;
    private String BookingTime;
    private String UserName;
    private String Rating;

    public RequestClass(String Id,String bookingTime,String userName,String rating){
        this.Id=Id;
        this.BookingTime=bookingTime;
        this.UserName=userName;
        this.Rating=rating;
    }

    public String getId(){return Id; }
    public String getBookingTime(){return BookingTime; }
    public String getUserName(){return UserName; }
    public String getRating(){return Rating; }


}
```

Main Activity:

```
 ArrayList<RequestClass> _requestList;
    _requestList=new ArrayList<>();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(result);
                        JSONArray JO = jsonobject.getJSONArray("Record");
                        JSONObject object;
                        for (int i = 0; i < JO.length(); i++) {
                            object = (JSONObject) JO.get(i);

                            _requestList.add(new RequestClass( object.optString("playerID"),object.optString("booking_time"),
                                    object.optString("username"),object.optString("rate") ));
                        }//end of for loop

                        RequestCustomAdapter adapter = new RequestCustomAdapter(context, R.layout.requestlayout, _requestList);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Custom Adapter Class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by wajid on 1/12/2018.
 */

class RequestCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RequestClass> {
    Context mContext;
    int mResource;
    public RequestCustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,ArrayList<RequestClass> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mContext=context;
        mResource=resource;
    }
    public static class ViewHolder{
        RelativeLayout _layout;
        TextView _bookingTime;
        TextView _ratingTextView;
        TextView _userNameTextView;
        Button acceptButton;
        Button _rejectButton;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
       final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView=inflater.inflate(mResource,parent,false);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder._layout = convertView.findViewById(R.id.requestLayout);
            holder._bookingTime = convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookingTime);
            holder._userNameTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
            holder._ratingTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
            holder.acceptButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.AcceptRequestButton);
            holder._rejectButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.RejectRequestButton);

            holder._rejectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, holder._rejectButton.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            holder.acceptButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, holder.acceptButton.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }
        else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        }
        holder._bookingTime.setText(getItem(position).getBookingTime());
        if(!getItem(position).getUserName().equals("")){

            holder._userNameTextView.setText(getItem(position).getUserName());
        }
        if(!getItem(position).getRating().equals("")){
            holder._ratingTextView.setText(getItem(position).getRating());
        }
        return  convertView;
    }

}
```

ListView in Main xml:

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:id="@+id/AllRequestListView">

    </ListView>
```

Resource Layout for list view requestlayout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/requestLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bookingTime"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bookingTime"
        android:text="Temp Name"
        android:id="@+id/userName"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
        android:text="No Rating"
        android:id="@+id/rating"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/AcceptRequestButton"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rating"
        android:text="Accept"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/RejectRequestButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/AcceptRequestButton"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="Reject"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In getview method put listener outside checking the view..try to follow this..it worked in my case..[How to Increase or decrease value of edittext in listview's each row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264186/how-to-increase-or-decrease-value-of-edittext-in-listviews-each-row)

Answer (score 0):

I find

```
final Button yourButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.your_button);
yourButton.setFocusable(false);
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        ...///);
```

can solve the problem. If you want to get some data when clicking the button, using tags is helpful. Here the button is declared final because it will be used within inner class.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: is it supposed to be an answer?

Comment: I just add the first line before setting an OnClickListener, and it seems working, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

**FOR KOTLIN USERS**

inside your getView(...) method if you try to start an activity through button onClickListener:

```
   myButton.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(this@CurrentActivity, SecondActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
   }
```

Pass the correct pointer for "this"