# How to have android longClick event to textView and not in the editText

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I try to implement a longClick in the my list view but I get longClick only in the edit text field: how I can get longClick only over the textView?

Thanks, Daniele

---

Other details:

- the main layout is "activity_main.xml" and in the list view "listView_listData" I put the "row.xml" layout with "RigaAdvAdapter" class;
- the layout "row.xml" has two field: textView and editText;
- I used a ArrayList to store the data that I want to view in the rows (separated by commas - Ex. "viewTextValue,editTextValue");
- I need to get longClick in the each row to offer more options;
- I dont't need the longClick in the editText otherwise the copy-paste not work;
- In the future I'll need more data, and so I'll use an array of ArrayList;

---

######################### LAYOUT: activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_listData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:fadingEdge="none" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

######################### LAYOUT: row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"  android:stretchColumns="*" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_rowData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewField"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:focusable="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextField"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:inputType="text">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
    ArrayList<String> arrayDataSource= new ArrayList<String>();

    ...
    I fill the array "arrayDataSource" with a string as "text,another text"
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView_listData  =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_listData);
        listView_listData.setAdapter(new RigaAdvAdapter());

        listView_listData.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
            {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int pos, long arg3)
                {
                mostraToast("hh long click"+String.valueOf(pos));
                return true;
                }
            });
        }
```

**Adapter class**

```
    public class RigaAdvAdapter extends BaseAdapter
        {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {return arrayDataSource.size();}
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {return position;}
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {return position;}
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
            if (convertView == null)
                {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                }

            TextView textViewField = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewField);
            EditText editTextField = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editTextField);

            String StringData=arrayDataSource.get(position);
            String[] ArrayStringData=StringData.split(",",-1);

            String textViewField_val=ArrayStringData[0];
            String editTextField_val=ArrayStringData[1];
            textViewField.setText(textViewField_val);
            editTextField.setText(editTextField_val);

            return convertView;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try to set you edittext propert set clickable and focusable to false. As you have added Editttext so it will gets the first focus and touch event always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `longclick` to ListView you have to set it for TextView.In RigaAdvAdapter class you have to add this

```
  textViewField.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set you edittext property set clickable and focusable to false. As you have added Editttext so it will gets the first focus and touch event always.

And to add the Longclick event on `TextView` you will have to implement the longclick listener inside your adapter class.

```
     @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
        if (convertView == null)
            {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }

        TextView textViewField = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewField);
        EditText editTextField = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editTextField);

    textViewField.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

       @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
     });
        String StringData=arrayDataSource.get(position);
        String[] ArrayStringData=StringData.split(",",-1);

        String textViewField_val=ArrayStringData[0];
        String editTextField_val=ArrayStringData[1];
        textViewField.setText(textViewField_val);
        editTextField.setText(editTextField_val);

        return convertView;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use onItemLongClickListener inside getView method of the adapter. This question can help [Android : How to set onClick event for Button in List item of ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596199/android-how-to-set-onclick-event-for-button-in-list-item-of-listview)