# How to Increase or decrease value of edittext in listview's each row?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewholder

I create one `Listview`, in my `Listview` I have two `Buttons` and one `Edittext`. In my `Edittext` I want to increase the value of `Edittext` as per `Button`'s click. I followed so many tutorials, but still it's not working in my `Listview` can anyone help me with that?

I follow this tutorial:
http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/02/muftitouch-listview-multi-click.html

It shows: `Cannot refer to the non-final local variable holder defined in an enclosing scope`

---

Code:

```
public class UserCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
 Context context;
 int layoutResourceId;
 ArrayList<User> data = new ArrayList<User>();

 public UserCustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
   ArrayList<User> data) {
  super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
  this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
  this.context = context;
  this.data = data;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View row = convertView;
  UserHolder holder = null;

  if (row == null) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
   row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
   holder = new UserHolder();
   holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   holder.textAddress = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
   holder.textLocation = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
   holder.btnEdit = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button1);
   holder.btnDelete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button2);
   row.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
  }
  User user = data.get(position);
  holder.textName.setText(user.getName());
  //holder.textAddress.setText(user.getAddress());
  holder.textLocation.setText(user.getLocation());
  holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("Edit Button Clicked", "**********");
   /* Toast.makeText(context, "Edit button Clicked",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

    int mValue = Integer.parseInt(holder.textAddress.getText().toString());
    mValue--;
    if(mValue < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("not valid");
    }
    else
    {
        holder.textAddress.setText( ""+mValue );
    }
   }
  });
  holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("Delete Button Clicked", "**********");
   /* Toast.makeText(context, "Delete button Clicked",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
   }
  });
  return row;

 }

 static class UserHolder {
  TextView textName;
  EditText textAddress;
  TextView textLocation;
  Button btnEdit;
  Button btnDelete;
 }
}
```

Comment: make `final  UserHolder holder`

Comment: And don't assign null during declaration, or you won't be able to assign an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant access use local variables in this case, By the time the onClickListener is called the variables would have gone out of scope.

So instead you can set the ViewHolder as a tag for the button too, then you can access that in your onClick.

```
holder.btnEdit.setTag(holder);
holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     ViewHolder tagHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("Edit Button Clicked", "**********");
   /* Toast.makeText(context, "Edit button Clicked",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

    int mValue = Integer.parseInt(tagHolder.textAddress.getText().toString());
    mValue--;
    if(mValue < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("not valid");
    }
    else
    {
        tagHolder.textAddress.setText( ""+mValue );
    }
   }
  });
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: but right i have red line and shows Cannot refer to the non-final local variable holder defined in an enclosing scope

Comment: near this line     int mValue = Integer.parseInt(holder.textAddress.getText().toString());

Comment: mValue is fine, it is only defined locally. holder has to be final

Comment: Change ```UserHolder holder = null;``` to ```final UserHolder holder;```

Comment: final UserHolder holder = null; i did this way...now it shows red line near  holder = new UserHolder(); and says The final local variable holder cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment

Comment: try to declare mValue globally

Comment: i did..still isuue with holder

Comment: i have again updated my answer. try again edited answer

Comment: int mValue = Integer.parseInt(tagHolder.textAddress.getText().toString());

This line still needs correction. Corrected it. Should use tagHolder in place of holder.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Try declaring holder like this, and dont try to redeclare it later in the code.

`final UserHolder holder = new UserHolder();`

Final variables cant be reassigned

Comment: final UserHolder holder = null; i did this way...now it shows red line near holder = new UserHolder(); and says The final local variable holder cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment

Comment: It should be ```final UserHolder holder;```

Comment: When you use ```final UserHolder holder = new UserHolder();``` you can't make an assignment to holder in the `else` part

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau you are right..this one works final UserHolder holder ;...but final UserHolder holder = new UserHolder(); dint work

Comment: When you assign a value to a final variable, you can't change it. That's why you should only declare the final variable first, and then add the value later

Answer (score 1):

Use `final UserHolder holder;` instead of `UserHolder holder = new UserHolder()`.

Comment: can you tell if i want to do same thing with pageradapter extend class?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you want to do with pagerAdapter

Comment: in pageradapter i want to add same layout with two buttons and ediitext and want to perform same operation