# How can we give action on button in listview?

Tags: android, listview

I can not give onclicklistener to button in this list, I need to make the button invisible. How we make an action on button in this type json to listview?

```
MainActivity.java<br>
package info.androidhive.jsonparsing; 

import info.androidhive.jsonparsing.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import org.json.JSONException;

import org.json.JSONObject; 

import android.app.ListActivity; 

import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.AdapterView;

import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

import android.widget.ListAdapter;

import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;


1. List item

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                    .getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                    .getText().toString();

            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SingleContactActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
            in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                    String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                    String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                    String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL,
                        TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                        R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}

}
```

Help meto give onclicklistener to button in this list format

Comment: try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596199/android-how-to-set-onclick-event-for-button-in-list-item-of-listview

Comment: The community [has discussed begging for urgency in questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495), and has firmly resolved it is unacceptable.