# Android ListView How to get item id without clicking on the item

Tags: android, listview

My `ListView` item consists of the following components - `ImageView` and then under it there are two more `ImageViews` - `like` and `dislike`.

So when I click on either `like` or `dislike` I want to be able to get corresponding `ListView` item `id`.

The only way that I am able to do it at the moment is if I first click on the `ListView` item and then on the `like` `ImageView`.

My question is - is there any way to get corresponding `ListView` item `id` without having to first click on the `ListView` item and only then on the `like` `ImageView`?

Here is my code

```
cursorAdapter = new PostCursorAdapter(this, null, 0);

        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, final long l) {
                ivLike = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivLike);

                ivLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Log.d("Like","Like button for the post with id=" + l + " has been clicked");


                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

**I was able to solve it myself. What I needed to do was to add** **`setOnClickListener` to my `like` and `dislike` `ImageViews` not in `MainActivity` but in `PostCursorAdapter`. Thanks everyone!**

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit more. What you mean by 'corresponding item id'

Comment: you have to bind the click event of like image view in your list view adapter to get the item id

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596199/android-how-to-set-onclick-event-for-button-in-list-item-of-listview