# onClick event on button generated on ListView android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

How to set onclick event on buttons generated on ListView?

I have this Activity,

```
public class Weekly extends AppCompatActivity {

protected ListView planList = null;
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_weekly);
    planList  = findViewById( R.id.planList );
    displayList();
}

private void displayList(){
    ArrayList<String> planListArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    planListArray.add("Sunday");
    planListArray.add("Monday");
    planListArray.add("Tuesday");
    planListArray.add("Wednesday");
    planListArray.add("Thursday");
    planListArray.add("Friday");
    planListArray.add("Saturday");
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerowbtn, planListArray);
    planList.setAdapter( listAdapter );
    planList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                long arg3)
        {
            String value = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
            builder.setMessage(value);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}


}
```

This is the activity where ListView is displayed. 
This will display list of buttons.

Here is my weekly xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/color_gradient"
tools:context="bmicalculator.bmicalculator.Weekly">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/planList"
    android:layout_width="338dp"
    android:layout_height="442dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Next is my simplerowbtn xml,

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
android:color="#ffffff"
android:textSize="25sp"></Button>
```

What I need now is to allow user click the button and display a new page with different value based on button clicked. How can I add onClick event on the buttons?

Tried to use setOnItemClickListener, code updated.

Comment: OnItemClick listner and when your done using deprecated listview use Recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the onClick event in the getView method of the custom adapter class

Answer (score 0):

You need to design the custom Adapter for the same.

Please refer [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596199/android-how-to-set-onclick-event-for-button-in-list-item-of-listview)