# Android Studio save drawableLeft icon on listview item click

Tags: android, listview

I'm having a little problem that I can't solve and I searched the net and I can't find an answer to it. I am making a small android application for my phone and I have a listview item with few items in it. On click on some of the item from my listView, I want to show a little check mark on the left side so a user can see what he selected. Next time the user opens or enters that Activity, there should already be check marker on what he clicked last time.

[image: listview item example]

I set the drawableLeft icon like this but now every listView item I have has the same check marker.

```
public class BazaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<bazeKlasa>
{
    private Context mContext;
    int mResource;


public BazaAdapter(@NonNull Context mContext, int resource, @NonNull 
ArrayList<bazeKlasa> objects) {
    super(mContext, resource, objects);
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mResource = resource;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull 
ViewGroup parent) {

    String imeBaze = getItem(position).getBaza();
    String nazivBaze = getItem(position).getImeBaze();

    bazeKlasa Baza = new bazeKlasa(imeBaze, nazivBaze);


    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource,parent,false);

    TextView TextGornji = (TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblcountryname);
    TextGornji.setText(nazivBaze);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change background color of selected item on a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976431/change-background-color-of-selected-item-on-a-listview)

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: pop, this is my Adapter Class.

Comment: How can you check which have the check mark icon? And another thing If you want to do set check mark for only selected items then please set drawable programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

On `getView()` method, you need to set drawable programmatically based on your check-in which item has the tick mark and which have not.

Hope this will help.

```
    TextView TextGornji = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblcountryname);

    // Provide your condition here instead of isShow
    if (isShow) {
        Drawable img = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tick); //Provide tick mark drawable
        img.setBounds(0, 0, 60, 60);
        TextGornji.setCompoundDrawables(img, null, null, null);
    } else {
        TextGornji.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable define

```
  private int mSelectedItem = -1;
```

and getView method to add this code

```
 if(mSelectedItem==position)
        {
            holder.textview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_right, 0,
                    0, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.textview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_blank, 0,0, 0);
        }
```

and click event to add this code

```
  mSelectedItem = getAdapterPosition();
  notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Tnx, i will try it now. Can you just tell me what do you mean by "holder"?
i hope this will help :)

Comment: holder is a recyclerView adapter method object like        (   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final SizeViewHolder holder, int position) )

Comment: so far so good, 
 TextGornji.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_right, 0, 0, 0);
but for some reason  "getAdapterPosition()" is red to me and i dont know what to do. 
Any reason why this is happening? Should i change something?

Comment: you are replace by  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: and follow this link useful for you.....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596199/android-how-to-set-onclick-event-for-button-in-list-item-of-listview