# Custom ListView has a Button - How to detect which row the button was pressed on?

Tags: java, android, listview, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I'm making an inventory tracker app for `Android` for a practice project. I use `SQLite` for the storage and my `ListView` displays the contents of the database using a `CursorAdapter`. I use `CursorLoader` to fetch the data from the database

Each row in my `ListView` has a couple of `TextViews` and a `Button`. I plan to use the `Button` to decrement the quantity column/property of the selected item in the database.

Where do I setup the button `OnClick` listener? In my `Activity` class or my `CursorAdapter` class' `bindView()`?

Also how can I detect which row the button was pressed on from the button click?

I've already used the ListView's `onItemClickListener` to send the user to a detailed Activity that display more info about the current row. That had an id argument that gets passed. So I'm finding an equivalent that I can use for the buttons I put on each row.

Comment: Suppose in `CursorAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Look the following. I used the Custom adapter to add the onItemClickListener:

```
private class MyListAdapter(val ctx: Context, val values: List<MyListInformatin>) : ArrayAdapter<MyListInformatin>(ctx, -1, values) {
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
         val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_my_layout, parent, false)
        rowView.setOnClickListener {
            val detailsActivity = Intent(ctx, DetailsActivity::class.java)
            detailsActivity.putExtra(DetailsActivity.ROUTE_NUMBER_PARAM, values.get(position).routeNumber)
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putParcelable(detailsActivity.ROUTE_NO_STRUCTURE_PARAM, values.get(position).strucutre)
            detailsActivity.putExtra(detailsActivity.PARAM_BUNDLE, bundle)
            ctx.startActivity(detailsActivity)
        }
        return rowView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface inside your adapter and a declare a fucntion in this interfae like ** void itemClick(int position)** and  implement that interface in your activity

for void itemClick(int position) method :- Define it on

```
holder.setOnClickListener() block like -

 viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

            @Override  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                if (yourInterface != null) {  
                    yourInterface.itemClick(position);  
                }  

            }  
        });
```

**For detailed description refer the below link -**

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9e8439/create-custom-listener-on-button-in-listitem-listview-in-a/

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered already, you need to setup your list items as not clickable and manually listen for `onClick` events of buttons, see a detailed answer here: [Android : How to set onClick event for Button in List item of ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596199/android-how-to-set-onclick-event-for-button-in-list-item-of-listview)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extend Adapter {
    private MyOnClickListener mListener;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        ...

        // Your view
        mContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                mListener.onWholeItemClick(position);
            }
        });

        // Your button
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                mListener.onButtonClick(position);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setListener(MyOnClickListener listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    // Listener interface
    public interface MyOnClickListener() {
        void onWholeItemClick(int position); // Can pass data as a parametter
        void onButtonClick(int position); 
    }
}

public class MyActivity extend Activity implement MyOnClickListener() {
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(...) {
        mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this);
        mAdapter.setListener(this); // Pass the listener to adapter
    }

    @Override
    public void onWholeItemClick(int position) {
        // 
    }

    @Override 
    public void onButtonClick(int position) {
        //
    }

}
```

That how you can fully hanhle click events

Answer (score 0):

In `onBindViewHolder` give a tag to that button. that tag can be the position of item or the item itself . ( tag can be object )

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemHolder, position: Int) {
   CUSTOMMODEL item = items[position];
   ...
   holder.button.setTag(item);
   //OR
   holder.button.setTag(position);
   ...
   holder.button.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
}
```

in your `onClick(View view)` method, get tag from the view and you can understand which item is clicked.