# setOnClickListener on listview doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener

I am building an app that has a listview.In the listview,I added a button to remove item.I made a function to remove item using sqlite.

The problem is that the button doesn't work when i press it to remove item.
and the logcat doesn't show any errors.

button in listview items:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/del_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="144dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:onClick="delete_item"
  />
```

fun to remove item:

```
fun delete_item(view:View){

//delete record
    var del_btn=findViewById<Button>(R.id.del_btn)

    del_btn.setOnClickListener {

        var check_box_id=del_btn.text
        var get_number_only=check_box_id.replace("[^0-9]".toRegex(),"")
        //creating the instance of DatabaseHandler class
        val databaseHandler: DatabaseHandler = DatabaseHandler(this@ListInvests)
        //calling the deleteEmployee method of DatabaseHandler class to delete record
        val status = databaseHandler.deleteEmployee(
            DeleteModelClass(
                Integer.parseInt(get_number_only)

            )
        )
        if (status > -1) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "record deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Did you tried checking if the listener works or is there a problem in deleting the record?

Comment: tried debug....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that i didn't add the listener in the **Adatper** Class of listview.
So,i added the listener to the adapter class,and attach the findViewById to rowview

Answer from [mukesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12596403/1136999) solved this issue.

```
 //delete record
    var del_btn=rowView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.del_btn)

    del_btn.setOnClickListener {

        var check_box_id=del_btn.text
        var get_number_only=check_box_id.replace("[^0-9]".toRegex(),"")
        //creating the instance of DatabaseHandler class
        val databaseHandler: DatabaseHandler = DatabaseHandler(context)
        //calling the deleteEmployee method of DatabaseHandler class to delete record
        val status = databaseHandler.deleteEmployee(
            DeleteModelClass(
                Integer.parseInt(get_number_only)

            )
        )
        if (status > -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "record deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }


    }
```