# How to add onclick on button event in listview android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, android-adapter

[Preview of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJvmF.png)

This is my preview of my app. My app receives values from google sheet. **You can see the buttons plus and minus. Listview includes two values which are from the sheet & and three values are increment buttons & quantity edittext.**

> So my question is how to add on click event on buttons to increment and change the value of quantity edittext

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/productTakingList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

    </ListView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

list_item_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_brand"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_brand"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/takingProduct"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
                android:text="Product"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_brand"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/takingRate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
                android:text="Rate"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/product"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.38" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/takingPlus"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:background="#0B0A0A"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/takingQty"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_box_24"
                tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/takingQty"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#070707"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/takingMinus"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/takingMinus"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="33dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:background="#0B0A0A"
                android:onClick="minus"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_indeterminate_check_box_24"
                tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ListItem.java

```
public class ListItem extends AppCompatActivity
{
    ListView listView;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog loading;
    EditText qty;
    ImageView plusImg,minusImg;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.productTakingList);
        qty=findViewById(R.id.takingQty);
        plusImg=findViewById(R.id.takingPlus);
        minusImg=findViewById(R.id.takingMinus);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        getItems();
    }

    private void getItems() {

        loading =  ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading","please wait",false,true);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "My Web App URL is here",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        parseItems(response);
                    }
                },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }
        );

        int socketTimeOut = 50000;
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(stringRequest);

    }


    private void parseItems(String jsonResposnce) {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonResposnce);
            JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("items");


            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jo = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                String itemName = jo.getString("itemName");
                String price = jo.getString("price");


                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
                item.put("itemName", itemName);
                item.put("price",price);

                list.add(item);


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,list,R.layout.list_item_row,
                new String[]{"itemName","price",},new int[]{R.id.takingProduct,R.id.takingRate});


        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        loading.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: You probably want to use an adapter. Also, have you checked this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596199/android-how-to-set-onclick-event-for-button-in-list-item-of-listview

Comment: check this tutorial to fix above task _https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9e8439/create-custom-listener-on-button-in-listitem-listview-in-a/_

Comment: Thanks... Mohd Qasim